# Javascript:How to getElementById from element created dynamically by script

Tags: javascript

I am playing around some code where I want to access the element which is created dynamicaaly by script. When I am trying to access this by using getElementById it is responding with
**TypeError: ...getElementById is not a function**.

**code**

```
const testConnectText = "Hello";
const daParent=document.getElementById("test");
const tagDiv = "<p style='text-align: center;'><span class='status' id='connectTest'></span></span></p>";

const statusConnecting = tagDiv.getElementById("connectTest");
statusConnecting = testConnectText;
daParent.innerHTML=tagDiv;
document.body.appendChild(daParent);
```

any suggestion how to get this and pass the updated text here ?

Comment: `tagDiv` is a string not an HTMLElement or Node.

Comment: @Tammy You have to actually add it to the `DOM` with a call to `appendChild` before you can locate it with `getElementById`

Comment: @RandyCasburn how can I access this with getElementbyId ?

Comment: Move lines 4 & 5 below `daParent.innerHTML`, change `tagDiv` to `daParent`

Comment: Also, the last line is unecessary as `daParent` is already in the DOM.

Comment: oh - typo - I didn't mean change `tagDiv` to `daParent` I meant change it to `document` - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementById` method only exists on the document, rather than on HTMLElements. You can only use `document.getElementById`, so if you need to find something by id inside a particular element you can use a query selector and a `#`. However, what you have is not an element but a string. It would be preferable to construct your new HTML by doing something like this:

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.style.textAlign = 'center';

const span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add('status');
span.setAttribute('id', 'connectTest');

p.append(span);
```

Once you've done this, it's possible for you to use `p.querySelector('#connectTest')` but there wouldn't really be any reason to do that since you already have the span stored in a variable called `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as a starting point (not change the way you've chosen to do this), this is your solution.

By moving the accessor to below the call to `.innerHTML`, the element will be in the DOM. As pointed out. `.getElementById()` is only available on the `document` object.

So this shows the simple changes necessary:

```js
const testConnectText = "Hello";
const daParent=document.getElementById("test");
const tagDiv = "<p style='text-align: center;'><span class='status' id='connectTest'></span></span></p>";

daParent.innerHTML=tagDiv;
const statusConnecting = document.getElementById("connectTest");
console.log(statusConnecting.id);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

It should be noted that there can be some security risks using `.innerHTML`, but that is a topic for a different question.